# delete first and last hyphen character from each column

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to remove the first and last characters from two separate columns prior to them being saved to a file. The characters I need to remove are the hyphens. Due to hyphens in the results, I am unable to just remove all of them. Is there a more effective way to use awk for this?

my current thoughts are something similar to this command.

```
cat file.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $2, $4}' | sed 's/.//;s/.$//' > newfile.txt
```

file example

```
1-|-40939-23-|-column-3-|-column-4-|
2-|-9832651-23-|-column-3-|-column-4-|
```

current output

```
40939-23- -column-4  
9832651-23- -column-4
```

desired output

```
40939-23 column-4 
9832651-23 column-4
```

Comment: Try `awk -F'|' '{gsub(/^-|-$/,"", $2);gsub(/^-|-$/,"", $4);print $2 " " $4;}' newfile.txt > tmp && mv tmp newfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'-[|](-|$)' '{print $2, $4}' file
40939-23 column-4
9832651-23 column-4
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realise the command could be reduced to this, works perfect. Thanks Ed Morton.

Comment: also `-F'-\\|-?'`

Comment: wrt `\\|` vs `[|]` - whenever you need 2 backslashes I prefer to use a bracket expression as it's the same number of chars but IMHO a bit clearer. wrt `-?` vs `(-|$)` - the OP showed that you can have `-|` at the end of a line and in that context it must be treated as a separator but he didn't say whether `-|` could occur in the middle of a line and, if so whether it should be treated as a separator in that context or not so I prefer the latter because I **know** it will behave as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk -F"|" '{gsub(/^-|-$/,"",$2);gsub(/^-|-$/,"",$(NF-1));print $2,$(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using field numbers considering that your Input_file will be always same.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[-|]";OFS="-"}{print $4 OFS $5 " " $12 OFS $13}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for this RavinderSingh, I think I can see what you are doing in this code but I could get either to work for me.